# Where do I find a good .NET library for synchronise files over FTP, HTTP and SMB

Tags: .net, http, ftp, synchronization, smb

I need a .NET library to synchronise files from a server to a client (one way).

Requirements:

- Should be a .NET library
- Needs to be deployed via ClickOnce (that is, no instalation, no COM etc.)
- Needs to support HTTP and/or FTP and/or SMB
- Open Source, Free or Commercial

Comment: I'm looking for a car that seats four, costs 2000 bucks, gets 100 miles/gallon and makes my insurance company stop raising their rates.  It's been a while, I'm considering settling for two of those right now.

Answer (score 1):

[Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx) will work for this.

Comment: It can be included in a .NET app as a dll reference and then deployed via click once.

Comment: Still it's an installation... right? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=109DB36E-CDD0-4514-9FB5-B77D9CEA37F6&displaylang=en

Comment: Isn't that in your requirement that is needs to be deployed via ClickOnce? Maybe I'm missing the question here, but ClickOnce is just a windows install that handles the install process and subsequent updates.

Comment: You convinced me. I'm looking at it now. I was hoping that there would be a small assembly for my needs. An entire framework is a bit to overwhelming for my current needs.

Comment: Sync framework only supports SMB, neither HTTP or FTP. I know I was not clear on that one.